# Is a black hole really a hole in space?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, topology, event-horizon, singularities

What if when a supernova occurs, instead of it condensing into a singularity it creates enough force to tear a hole into the fabric of space? Is a [black hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) just what is sounds like, a hole in space?

Comment: What does "a hole in space" even mean?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Let $(M,g)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold $M$ with Lorentz metric $g$. An open subset $U\subset M$ is said to contain a *hole in space* if there exists a spacelike set $\Sigma\subset U$ that is disconnected. /s

Answer (score 2):

No. Spacetime is smooth and continuous everywhere except at the central singularity. If you jumped into a big enough black hole you would cross the event horizon without noticing anything special happening.

The requirement for it to be a big black hole is because the tidal forces at the event horizon decrease with increasing black hole size. Jump into a small black hole and you will be [spaghettified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification) before you reach the horizon. But even with a small black hole spacetime remains smooth and continuous - you just wouldn't be alive to appreciate it.

If you're interested there are some animations of a trip into a black hole [on this web site](http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/schw.html).

Comment: +1 for *spaghettified*, I didn't know this terminology :D